# Make custom function using dynamic variable

Tags: qgis-custom-function

In the function editor, I am trying to make this function :

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def size_reduction( x, feature, parent):
    s = @map_scale/1000/x
    y = if( s<1, s, 1+ln(s) )
    return y
```

But I get the error shown below.
Can anyone help me ?

```
An error occurred during execution of following code:
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def size_reduction( x, feature, parent):
    s = @map_scale/1000/x
    y = if( s    return y





  File "", line 6
    s = @map_scale/1000/x
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version:
3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15)
[GCC 9.3.0]

QGIS version:
3.16.4-Hannover 'Hannover', exported

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the map scale within a function using

```
from qgis.utils import iface
[...]
iface.mapCanvas().scale()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working function

```
import math  
from qgis.utils import iface  
from qgis.core import *  
from qgis.gui import *  
  
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')  
def size_reduction( x, feature, parent):  
    s = iface.mapCanvas().scale()/1000/x  
    if s<1 :  
        y = s  
    else :  
        y = 1+math.log(s)          
    return y
```